# Azure: Unable to copy data from one azure storage account from one subscription to another subscription

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage-account

I am trying to copy data from one azure storage account in one subscription to other azure storage account in different subscription. For that I had created an azure function using powershell script.

This script is working fine when copy content from one storage account to other storage account but doesn't work for different subscription.

```
$SrcStgAccURI = "https://trimarinestage.blob.core.windows.net/"
$SrcSASToken = "?sr=b&sv=2019-12-12&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rlx&se=2024-09-23T16:19:37Z&st=2020-09-23T08:19:37Z&spr=https&sig=tVcutYO6P2ytRpiEahO92wCJZh8I5ORRS7JYKtI2ADU%3D"
$SrcFullPath = "$($SrcStgAccURI)?$($SrcSASToken)"

$DstStgAccURI = "https://backuptops.file.core.windows.net/"
$DstSASToken = "?sv=2020-08-04&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacuptfx&se=2025-09-13T23:07:44Z&st=2021-09-13T15:07:44Z&spr=https&sig=Dj9myrNkmNp5GCbs31yDiV5zsyz41EJfnY8sJ9oaAWM%3D"
$DstFullPath = "$($DstStgAccURI)?$($DstSASToken)"
```

Getting following error:

> 2021-09-16T07:30:04.614 [Error] Executed 'Functions.BackUp' (Failed,
> Id=2e0f1798-8b9c-45fc-b652-7350daa4fceb, Duration=42ms)Could not
> create BlobServiceClient to obtain the BlobContainerClient using
> Connection: Storage

Comment: i am using following code:


Write-Host "Backing up storage account..."
    ./azcopy.exe copy $SrcFullPath $DstFullPath --recursive --overwrite=ifsourcenewer

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my environment, and it is working for me Please use the below formatted command.

```
$SrcStgAccURI = "https://a********storragetest.blob.core.windows.net/"
$SrcSASToken = "sastoken with proper permissions"
$SrcFullPath = "$SrcStgAccURI"+"$SrcSASToken"
$DstStgAccURI = "https://a*********storageaccount234.file.core.windows.net/"
$DstSASToken = "sastoken with proper permissions"
$DstFullPath = "$DstStgAccURI"+"$DstSASToken"
```

Use the SAS Token with below permission.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]